# Unpacking MSI in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, installation

I have an installer that deploys web services to IIS.  After this has finshed a custom action fires that updates the database with the scripts required by the webservices.  The scripts are currently deploying to IIS aswell because they are part of the .net project.  How can I configure the installation process so the scripts arn't part of the project and get un-packed from the MSI so my custom action can access them?

Comment: Are you using the web deployment project in visual studio?

Comment: There may be a flag you can set somewhere, why not just remove them at the end of the custom action?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the standard Visual Studio setup projects do this:

1. Add your scripts as files to your setup project
2. Right-click on the files
3. Select "Properties"
4. Change the "PackageAs" property to "vsdpaLoose"

Your files will now be output alongside your MSI so will be available at any time.

Answer (score 0):

Using WIX, sorry no clue as to what you are using.  I would create a

```
<Binary Id="webServiceScript.sql" src="[DirectoryToFile]\webServiceDataScript.sql" />
```

After setup a CA to run the script

```
<CustomAction Id="CallCmd" Value="[Path_to_Exe_Folder][Your_EXE_TO_RUN_SCRIPT_HERE]" />

<CustomAction Id="RunCmd" ExeCommand="webServiceScript.sql" BinaryKey="webServiceScript.sql" Return="Ignore" />
```

Then just Setup the Installation Sequence

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="CallCmd" Before="InstallFinalize" />
  <Custom Action="RunCmd" After="CallCmd" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```